# omp barrier nested threads

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I have a c++ OpenMP code that looks about this:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread), num_threads(ncpu)
{
    <some code>
    #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(close), num_threads(ncore)
    {
        <some more code...>
         #pragma omp barrier
    }/* End of Level 2 threads*/
}/* End of Level 1 threads*/
```

This will create 2 levels of nested threading (total 16 threads). My problem is that I need the barrier to extend over both layers of threading. As it is right now each Level 2 group of 8 threads will wait on its group members but when one group is finished it will move on regardless of the other group of 8 threads. Is there a way to create a barrier that operates on the top level? (without terminating the L2 parallel region and re-create it)

Comment: sorry, just forgot about them in the example... I do have them in the real code

Comment: but if total threads were 100k, it would need to keep 100k stacks in memory switch between them at each barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `barrier` directive only applies to the current team, so here your level 2 ones. If really terminating this level 2 isn't an option, then I guess that something like this could work:

```cpp
int nbDone = 0;
#pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread), num_threads(ncpu)
{
    <some code>
    #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(close), num_threads(ncore)
    {
        <some more code...>
        // here is the "inter-team barrier"
        #pragma omp atomic update
        ++nbDone;
        bool allDone = false;
        while ( !allDone ) {
            #pragma omp barrier
            #pragma omp atomic read
            allDone = nbDone == ncpu * ncore;
        }
        // End of the "inter-team barrier"
    }/* End of Level 2 threads*/
}/* End of Level 2 threads*/
```

I haven't tested it but I think that should work. However, I still believe you'd better off just finishing your L2 teams, put a `barrier`at L1 and strat back your L2 teams...